# Node, Express, MYSQL Retrieving JSON from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have stored JSON in a database like under the accesssPoint field. It looks exactly like this:

```
{"mode": "client", "rate": 0, "ssid": "RMG", "signal": 0, "channel": 0, "password": "", "username": "example@aol.com"}
```

I run a MYSQL query from within Node and for some reason I get this as output:

```
[{"accessPoint":"[{\"mode\": \"client\", \"rate\": 0, \"ssid\": \"RMG\", \"signal\": 0, \"channel\": 0, \"password\": \"\", \"username\": \"example@aol.com\"}]"}]
```

when I use:

```
db.query('SELECT accessPoint FROM player_r WHERE id=?', [playerID], function (err, results) {
         var secondQuery = [];

         results.forEach(function (item) {
         secondQuery.push(item);
         });

                res.send(results);
            });
```

Could someone please help me to extract this JSON the correct way? Help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results that came back are an array of objects, where each object's only property is "accessPoint". That value of that property is the JSON string your stored in the database. You'll need to `JSON.parse` to get some values.

You could also use a library like [knexJS](http://knexjs.org/)  to make calls to the database. The docs are great, the results are JSON objects, and it likely can use the same [SQL driver library](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-node) you're using right now.

MySQL also has a specific [JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) but you would need to use that query syntax rather than just a plain `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. I dont think it has too much to do with the way I query the JSON from MYSQL but I might be wrong. When I do a console.log of the results, there are no added slashes. However, when I do a res.send or res.json, I get the added slashes. Whenever I try to JSON.parse the results, I get an error in my console (Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1).

Comment: You should try a `typeof` on your raw response. When you console log, is it JSON (`typeof results.accesspoint === 'object'`) or does it just look like JSON (`typeof results.accesspoint === 'string'`)?

Comment: `console.log(typeof results === 'string')`
`console.log(typeof results === 'object')`
`console.log(typeof results === 'array')`
`console.log(typeof results.accessPoint === 'object')`
`console.log(typeof results.accessPoint === 'string')`
`console.log(typeof results.accessPoint === 'array')` I ran all of the following and they were all false expect for `console.log(typeof results === 'object')`

Comment: `parsed = JSON.stringify(results);        res.status(500).json(parsed);`  Creates extra slashes in the res.send response that looks like this:  `"[{\"accessPoint\":\"[{\\\"mode\\\": \\\"client\\\", \\\"rate\\\": 0, \\\"ssid\\\": \\\"RMG\\\", \\\"signal\\\": 0, \\\"channel\\\": 0, \\\"password\\\": \\\"\\\", \\\"username\\\": \\\"Martin.Johnsson@rmgnetworks.com\\\"}]\"}]"`

Comment: not `results`, what is the type of `results[0].accesspoint` (i.e The first object in the results array, and the property `accesspoint` of that object). Also, if you did `var point = results[0].accesspoint;`, what is the `typeof` of that, and what does `console.log(point)` print out?